# Apache virtualhost - Mac OSX 10.7.3

Tags: macos, apache

After upgrading to Lion, all my virtualhosts stopped working. They redirect to "It works" main apache page on my device for some weird reason.

Example:

/etc/hosts:
`127.0.0.1  myhost.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/testproj/"
    ServerName myhost.com

    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/testproj/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/testproj-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/testproj-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Did anyone else face the same issue? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple causes to this issue.

First, have you tried restarting Apache?
You can do so by typing `sudo apachectl graceful` in the Terminal.

If that doesn't work out, try to create a folder in the predestined folder (Sites), and see if it works. Alsoo, make sure you've enabled the proper settings: 
[image]

And just for the record, my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file (on a Windows though) looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.test.be
    ErrorLog "logs/test.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test.log" common
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\me\workspace\test\drupal"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Tried all... nothing happened. The virtualhost configs are unchanged since the upgrade and they used to be working quite fine

Answer (score 0):

Where is that snippet of VirtualHost config? Are you sure it's being read in?

I notice that by default, the `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file is not read in by the main `httpd.conf` so you'd have to uncomment the line to read it in.

You can check what Apache thinks of the current vhost config with

```
sudo httpd -S
```

and verify that your myhost.com is there.

Please update your question with the results of this if it's not the problem so we can start narrowing it down.